# Jooq Loggerlistener query executed time inconsistency

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I am using JOOQ with Postgres dialect to fire query from my spring boot app and the RDS is postgres.
The query being fired is -

```
select contents::jsonb #> '{columns,0}' 
from nebula.test where (id=4)
```

Java side code:

```java
Field<Object> selectField = DSL.field("contents::jsonb #> {0}",Object.class, DSL.inline("{columns,0}"));  
SelectConditionStep<Record1<Object>> resultQuery= dslContext.select(selectField).from("test").where("id=4");  
Result<Record1<Object>> result = resultQuery.fetch();
```

**Stats from Jooq Loglisteners:**

```
o.j.t.LoggerListener : Executing query          : select contents::jsonb #> '{columns,0}' from test where (id=4)  
DEBUG [http-bio-8443-exec-6] -
            o.j.t.StopWatch : Query executed           : Total: 8.024ms
```

**Stats from Explain in Postgres directly**

```sql
explain analyze
select contents::jsonb #> '{columns,0}' from test where (id=4);  
Index Scan using test_pkey on test  (cost=0.13..8.15 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.114..0.116 rows=1 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (id = 4)
Planning time: 0.091 ms
Execution time: 0.089 ms
```

Why Jooq LogListener is showing some extra time?

Comment: The execution time reported by `explain analyze` does **not** including sending the data to the client, nor does it include the time the client needs to process the data.